# How to make a Telegram bot send messages daily? - Node.js

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm new to JS and I would like to ask for some help.
I'm developing a bot that sends some content daily once a user has it enabled. I'm using Telegraf library.

Could you please help me on how I can create something like this or maybe share some links or samples?

Is it possible with setInterval scheduling?

Maybe there are some node plugins that allow this feature?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Create bot

https://medium.com/swlh/build-own-telegram-bot-with-node-js-516b8f233585

for the daily message, you can use the Cron package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron